# Blender json export; "animation" missing

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

I'm trying to figure out how basic animations are exported and used with three.js. I made a geometry in blender and exported it to JSON. Since i'm useing three.js v 69, the use of THREE.animationHandler is deprecated. I found a working example for my version of the library, but it works only with the JSON that comes with the example that comes with the three.js library avalible here: http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/knight.js. 
MY JSON file outputs this error: `TypeError: a is undefined three.min.js:682`.

I can't find a syntax difference  between the files.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),  
    animatedMesh;

loader.load( './123.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
     var originalMaterial = materials[ 0 ];
    originalMaterial.skinning = true;
    animatedMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, originalMaterial );
    // Instantiate the animation
    var animation = new THREE.Animation(
        animatedMesh,
        geometry.animation
    );
    animation.play();

});
scene.add( animatedMesh );
```

When I check geometry.animation[0].hierarchy.lenght first in the function that the loader calls, it gives and error when I use my JSON. When I use knight.js I get the correct number of the animations; 80.

The JSON i exported for the test:

```
{   "metadata": {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 8,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [],
        "materials"     : 1,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 1
    },

        "scale" : 1.000000,

        "vertices" : [0.282971,-0.059365,-0.277163,0.278713,-0.0459321,0.283946,-0.282552,-0.0482188,0.279742,-0.278294,-0.0616519,-0.281367,0.268505,3.65467,-0.366188,0.264248,3.66811,0.194921,-0.297017,3.66582,0.190716,-0.29276,3.65239,-0.370392],
        "faces"    : [35,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,35,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,35,0,4,5,1,0,0,4,7,1,35,1,5,6,2,0,1,7,6,2,35,2,6,7,3,0,2,6,5,3,35,4,0,3,7,0,4,0,3,5],
        "uvs"      : [],
        "normals"  : [0.583941,-0.588641,-0.559008,0.575182,-0.560991,0.595325,-0.579455,-0.565691,0.586657,-0.570696,-0.593341,-0.567644,0.579455,0.565691,-0.586657,-0.575182,0.560991,-0.595325,-0.583941,0.588641,0.559008,0.570696,0.593341,0.567644],

        "skinIndices"  : [0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1],
        "skinWeights"  : [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        "morphTargets" : [],

        "bones"      : [{"parent":-1,"name":"Bone","pos":[0,0,-0],"rotq":[0.707107,0,-0,0.707107],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]}],
        "animation" : [{"name":"ArmatureAction","fps":24,"length":1.625,"hierarchy":[{"parent":-1,"keys":[{"time":0,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.0416667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.0833333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.125,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.166667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.208333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.25,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.291667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.333333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.375,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.416667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.458333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.5,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.541667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.583333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.625,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.666667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.708333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.75,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.791667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.833333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.875,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.916667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":0.958333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.04167,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.08333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.125,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.16667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.20833,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.25,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.29167,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.33333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.375,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.41667,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.45833,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.5,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.54167,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.58333,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]},{"time":1.625,"pos":[0,0,-0],"rot":[0.698582,-0.00125648,0.00407379,0.715517],"scl":[3.4158,3.4158,3.4158]}]}]}],

        "colors"    : [],
        "materials" : [
            {
                "DbgColor": 15658734,
                "DbgIndex": 0,
                "DbgName": "Material",
                "blending": "NormalBlending",
                "colorAmbient": [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
                "colorDiffuse": [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
                "colorEmissive": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                "colorSpecular": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                "depthTest": true,
                "depthWrite": true,
                "shading": "Lambert",
                "specularCoef": 50,
                "transparency": 1.0,
                "transparent": false,
                "vertexColors": false
            }       ]   }
```

Comment: Please include your source code and the JSON in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include your source code **in the question** (not some page where we have to enable JavaScript and run the code) and **minimal JSON** (not 1.267 MB).  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** (MCVE). Just the process of creating a MCVE can often let you find the issue.

Comment: It was my mistake, there are certain conditions in Blender to make the right export to JSON. Also in some models its cales animation, in mine its animations. The correct code is:     var animation = new THREE.Animation(
        animatedMesh,
        geometry.animations[0]
    );

Comment: If you have a solution for your problem, please add it as an answer.  You can then accept it.  It is perfectly acceptable for you to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, there are certain conditions in Blender to make the right export to JSON. Also in some models its cales animation, in mine its animations. The correct code is: var animation = new THREE.Animation( animatedMesh, geometry.animations[0] );